# Is onBeginningOfSpeech() triggered locally or by the server?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

The documentation for [onBeginningOfSpeech()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBeginningOfSpeech%28%29) says:

> [called when] The user has started to speak.

But it doesn't say whether this is microphone-identified (i.e. local) event or server-identified event (i.e. needs Google speech servers to acknowledge start-of-speech).

I tried to find clues in [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java#SpeechRecognizer.InternalListener.onBeginningOfSpeech%28%29), but at some point I got lost between the service, callbacks, interface... it's not a simple who-calls-who sequence.

Do you happen to know whether the [onBeginningOfSpeech()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBeginningOfSpeech%28%29) is performed locally (e.g. local circuit detects RMS change) or does it have to travel to Google servers and get their "yes/no"?

I know that the speech recognition itself travels to Google's servers, but is it done for [onBeginningOfSpeech()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBeginningOfSpeech%28%29) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. Out of curiosity I conducted a little test. In a sample application I disabled WiFi in `onReadyForSpeech()`:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

And observed what happens. Sure enough, `onBeginningOfSpeech()` is called as soon as he slightest noise is picked up by the mic. It doesn't even have to be speech.

So @KevinJunghans's conclusion is correct: `onBeginningOfSpeech()` isn't determined or initiated by the Google servers.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting the beginning of speech and end of speech would have to be performed locally because the system basically has to "listen" to determine when these events occur. This could not be performed efficiently with a remote service.  Looking for the beginning and end of speech in speech recognition is called end-pointing and sophisticated signal processing is used to determine this. For Google speech the client device determines when speech starts and begins recording, and then determines when the end of speech occurs to stop recording. On some systems the end-pointer is also responsible for removing excessive silence on both ends of the recording. Beginning of speech can also be triggered by a selection the user makes, for example clicking on the microphone icon on a web browser. This recorded audio is then sent to Google servers for analysis and the results returned. For more details on Google's unofficial API and how it handles this audio take a look at [this article](http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/).